# BATCH: Looking to "thread" commands and capture output to txt

Tags: batch-file

n00b here.
I am creating a simple batch file and need the following:

I have about 15 commands I need to "thread". Running a simple batch file forces me to wait after each command is executed to start the next. So my research lead me to the "START" command. This works but the new window created for each command disappears so research then lead me to "CALL" which keeps each window open after its executed so I can monitor the output. Next I needed to have each window output to a log file.

I cant seem to capture this info. Everything I have tried yields an empty txt file, although it does create the file itself.

Example.

```
ECHO Starting up processes  
start "Process 1" call ping www.google.com > Googleresults.txt  
start "Process 2" call ping www.apple.com > Appleresults.txt
```

Any ideas? Much appreciated!

Comment: I am a little unclear of what you want. you want to run the commands asyncronously or not? what was the problem with start on its own?

Comment: also, do you have to monitor the seperate windows, or are you happy with just the log files?

Comment: I need each command to run at the same time. I would like each command to open its own window so that I can monitor the results in real time, and also output each command to its own logfile. Thanks!

Comment: you are redirecting the output of `start` (which is empty) to the file. To assing the redirection to the command (`ping`), you have to escape it: `start "Process 1" call ping www.google.com ^> Googleresults.txt`. Sadly that means, the output goes (only) to the file. To have the output on the screen *and*  in the file, you need something like `tee` (google for "tee for windows", there are lots of variants)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be the easiest built in way to do this by utilizing powershell as well.

```
ping google.com>Googleresults.txt | start "process 1" powershell Get-Content Googleresults.txt -Wait -Tail 10 | ping apple.com>Appleresults.txt | start "process 2" powershell Get-Content Appleresults.txt -Wait -Tail 10
taskkill /FI "WINDOWTITLE eq process*">nul
```

You need to seperate each command with pipe `|` to start them asyncronously, it redirects to file and we pretty much start new windows and tail the files using powershell.

Comment: That worked! Thanks Gerhard! One more question, for ease of the eyes on the script itself, do I have to keep all the commands on one line or can I have each command on a line? Hopefully that makes sense.

Comment: @sfg possibly there is another way, but I cannot test is now, so for now, ugly will have to do :)

Comment: Thanks! Ok, so here is something else I am seeing.(I can live with the ugly btw ;)) So in my script after the multiple commands are executed the script will continue, with this new PS command I am seeing where the script does not. After it executes those commands it should proceed to a new command but instead is sitting there as if its waiting on the prior commands to complete.

Comment: You can add an exit to the powershell command. I will update the answer bit later. I am on my phone driving home.

Comment: Morning Gerhard, and input on the edit back to the command line? I was trying a bunch of things I found online but so far no luck. Thanks!

Comment: hmm. that didn't seem to work. I added the new code to the end of the line and then attempted this on its own line and still the same results.

Comment: What are your processes called? In my example we called them process 1 etc.

Comment: ah, did not realize that was tied into the naming. I would like to name each command according to the task. Is that possible? Or by calling them "Process 1, 2, 3" in your example not just a "name" but code that is needed in order to execute the "exit" code?

Comment: Well. Easiest would be to rename your process titles to something identifiable by you but also easier for the script. Like `_proc_Ping google` and  `_proc_Ping apple` then simply run `taskkill /FI "IMAGENAME eq _proc*"`

Comment: Gerhard, my issue was my testing on my end had "ping -t" for one of the commands. This forever switch was causing the issue. My apologies. I'm good now!  Supper appreciate your time.

Comment: Great. As long as you are sorted.